# socket.recvmsg is ignoring ancbufsize, ancillary data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Using a TCP socket, on a unix system, python is seemingly ignoring my ancbufsize completely.

```
data, ancdata, msg_flags, address = sock.recvmsg(1, socket.CMSG_LEN(4))
```

From the linux man page for recvmsg:

> size_t        msg_controllen; /* ancillary data buffer len */

If I strace my program, I see that msg_controllen is 0, I cant seem to do anything to get it to have a non-zero value. Is there some other package I need to install? Running pretty stock centos7

Here is the recvmsg call in my strace output:

```
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=0x7ffcc97e2c90, msg_iov(1)=[{"\360", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1
```

This returns only the msg_iov, and has no ancillary data, presumably because msg_controllen is 0.

the above returns "360"

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: @CristiFati 360, it should have ancillary data though, and msg_controllen should not be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How does ancillary data in sendmsg() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128345/how-does-ancillary-data-in-sendmsg-work)

I think that ancillary data is never sent over a TCP socket, frustrating that is not listed in many documents, including the python socket docs, c message docs, or even the APUE book